# Any GUI SILC client for Mac OS X that works?

Tags: macos, chat

We use SILC for secure IRC-like communications in the office; Pidgin works pretty well for this on Windows and Linux, but I can't seem to find a Mac client that works, other than the text-based one from ports.

[Colloquy](http://colloquy.info/) claims to support SILC, but it doesn't seem to do anything useful with the server's certificate; looking at the source, most of the SILC-related stuff is just empty stubs.

Answer (score 1):

Does Adium work? I seem to recall that at one time it supported SILC; however, I don't see it listed now. It's based on libpurple like Pidgin.

Comment: Nope, no SILC support in there either.